# Is there an Jasmine JS equivalent of setUpClass?

Tags: javascript, testing, jasmine

Is there some trick to run some code at the begining and at the end of a "describe" test suite?

I am looking for something similar to setUpClass/tearDownClass from XUnit

In this example, i want to run "login_as_admin" only once before all tests and "logout" only once after all tests.

Thanks!

Here is the sample code.

```
/*
Functional tests.
*/

describe('Services Page', function() {

    it('setUpClass', function() {
        login_as_admin()
    })

    /*
    Before each test make sure we are on the services page.
    */
    setup(function() {
        browser().navigateTo('/PAGE_UNDER_TEST')
    })

    it(
    'Click on add service will get us to the Add service page.',
    function() {
        element('#add-service').click()

        expect(browser().location().path()).toBe('/services/_add')
    })

    it(
    'Click on edit service will get us to the Edit service page.',
    function() {
        element('#edit-service').click()

        expect(browser().location().path()).toBe('/services/local-manager')
    })

    it('tearUpClass', function() {
        logout()
    })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few patches to jasmine ([1](https://github.com/nonplus/jasmine-beforeAll)) and ([2](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jasmine-before-all)) which support doing this.  However they do not appear to be well maintained.  I have moved away from Jasmine to [Mocha](http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/) for this very reason.

Comment: Thanks! -1 for Jasmine.  Mocha is a bit better but managing complex test suits is still ugly with a function based approach... after setUpClass and tearDownClass a want mixins and test inheritance and test generators :)

Comment: The functional ugliness can be significantly remediated if you switch to coffeescript as your implementation language.